# Reading ZIP file of machine-written data won't "plot" in RStudio

Tags: r, plot, encoding, zip

Summary:  Despite a complicated lead-up, the solution was very simple:  In order to plot a row of a dataframe as a line instead of a lattice, I needed to transpose the data in order to invert from x obs of y variables to y obs of x variables.

I am using RStudio on a Windows 10 computer.

I am using scientific equipment to write measurements to a csv file.  Then I ZIP several files and read to R using read.csv.  However, the data frame behaves strangely.  Commands "length" and "dim" disagree and the "plot" function throws errors.  Because I can create simulated data that doesn't throw the errors, I think the problem is either in how the machine wrote the data or in my loading and processing of the data.

Two ZIP files are located in my stackoverflow repository (with "Monterey Jack" in the name):
https://github.com/baprisbrey/stackoverflow

Here is my code for reading and processing them:

```
# Unzip the folders
unZIP <- function(folder){
  orig.directory <- getwd()
  setwd(folder)

  zipped.folders <- list.files(pattern = ".*zip")

  for (i in zipped.folders){
    unzip(i)}
  setwd(orig.directory)

}


folder <- "C:/Users/user/Documents/StackOverflow"

unZIP(folder)

# Load the data into a list of lists

pullData <- function(folder){
  orig.directory <- getwd()
  setwd(folder)


  #zipped.folders <- list.files(pattern = ".*zip")
  #unzipped.folders <- list.files(folder)[!(list.files(folder) %in% zipped.folders)]
  unzipped.folders <- list.dirs(folder)[-1] # Removing itself as the first directory.

  oData <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(unzipped.folders))
  names(oData) <- str_remove(unzipped.folders, paste(folder,"/",sep=""))
  for (i in unzipped.folders) {
    filenames <- list.files(i, pattern = "*.csv")
    #setwd(paste(folder, i, sep="/"))
    setwd(i)
    files <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, skip = 5, header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE") #Note unusual encoding
    oData[[str_remove(i, paste(folder,"/",sep=""))]] <- vector(mode="list", length = length(files))
    oData[[str_remove(i, paste(folder,"/",sep=""))]] <- files
  }

  setwd(orig.directory) 
  return(oData)
}

theData <- pullData(folder) #Load the data into a list of lists

# Process the data into frames
bigFrame <- function(bigList) {
  #where bigList is theData is the result of pullData

  #initialize the holding list of frames per set
  preList <- vector(mode="list", length = length(bigList))
  names(preList) <- names(bigList)

  # process the data
  for (i in 1:length(bigList)){
    step1 <- lapply(bigList[[i]],  t)  # transpose each data
    step2 <- do.call(rbind, step1)     # roll it up into it's own matrix #original error that wasn't reproduced:  It showed length(step2) = 24048 when i = 1 and dim(step2) = 48 501.  Any comments on why?
    firstRow <- step2[1,]              #holding onto the first row to become the names
    step3 <- as.data.frame(step2)      # turn it into a frame
    step4 <- step3[grepl("µA", rownames(step3)),] # Get rid of all those excess name rows
    rownames(step4) <- 1:(nrow(step4))            # change the row names to rowID's
    colnames(step4)  <- firstRow       # change the column names to the first row steps
    step4$ID <- rep(names(bigList[i]),nrow(step4)) # Add an I.D. column
    step4$Class[grepl("pos",tolower(step4$ID))] <- "Yes"  # Add "Yes" class
    step4$Class[grepl("neg",tolower(step4$ID))] <- "No"  # Add "No" class
    preList[[i]] <- step4  
  }

  #  bigFrame <- do.call(rbind, preList) #Failed due to different number of measurements (rows that become columns) across all the data sets
  #  return(bigFrame)

  return(preList) # Works!


}


frameList <- bigFrame(theData) 

monterey <- rbind(frameList[[1]],frameList[[2]])

# Odd behaviors
dim(monterey)    #48 503
length(monterey) #503 #This is not reproducing my original error of length = 24048

rowOne <- monterey[1,1:(ncol(monterey)-2)]

plot(rowOne) #Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

#describe the data
quantile(rowOne, seq(0, 1, length.out = 11) )
quantile(rowOne, seq(0, 1, length.out = 11) ) %>% plot #produces undesired lattice plot


# simulate the data
doppelganger <- sample(1:20461,501,replace = TRUE)
names(doppelganger) <- names(rowOne)

# describe the data
plot(doppelganger) #Successful scatterplot.  (With my non-random data, I want a line where the numbers in colnames are along the x-axis)
quantile(doppelganger, seq(0, 1, length.out = 11) ) #the random distribution is mildly different
quantile(doppelganger, seq(0, 1, length.out = 11) ) %>% plot # a simple line of dots as desired

# investigating structure

str(rowOne) # results in a dataframe of 1 observation of 501 variables.  This is a correct interpretation.
str(as.data.frame(doppelganger)) # results in 501 observations of 1 variable.  This is not a correct interpretation but creates the plot that I want.

How do I convert the rowOne to plot like doppelganger?
```

It looks like one of my errors is not reproducing, where calls to "dim" and "length" apparently disagree.
However, I'm confused as to why the "plot" function is producing a lattice plot on my processed data and a line of dots on my simulated data.

What I would like is to plot each row of data as a line.  (Next, and out of the scope of this question, is I would like to classify the data with adaboost.  My concern is that if "plot" behaves strangely then the classifier won't work.)

Any tips or suggestions or explanations or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  Investigating the structure with ("str") of the two examples explains the difference between plots.  I guess my modified question is, how do I switch between the two structures to enable plotting a line (like doppelganger) instead of a lattice (like rowOne)?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.
I am leaving behind the part about the discrepancy between "length" and "dim" since I can't provide a reproducible example.  However, I'm happy to leave up for comment.

The answer is that in order to produce my plot, I simply have to transpose the row as follows:

```
rowOne %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% plot
```

This inverts the structure from one observation of 501 variables to 501 obs of one variable as follows:

```
rowOne %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% str()
#'data.frame':  501 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ 1: num  8712 8712 8712 8712 8712 ...
```

Because of the unusual encoding I used, and the strange "length" result, I failed to see a simple solution to my "plot" problem.